# pdflatex insdljs error - undefined control sequence

Tags: pdftex

TeXworks v0.6.5 (MikTeX 2.9.7400 26/3/2020)

This is my first time with pdflatex, I am learning something every minute, so I hope I have the terminology right. I have been asked to troubleshoot a system that builds a PDF showing a drawing border and zoomable map content. It also has some inbuilt tick boxes in the resultant PDF the user can interact with and control the zoomable content.

Someone has written the front end in the CAD application which generates three files. There is a .js file, a .tex file with the assembly instructions for tex, and a u3d file which contains the zoomable map content. How I imagine this working is tex/pdflatex runs and builds the final PDF, which is the part that is failing so no PDF is generated. After installing MikTeX I can use the console to see what it happening (the log file is also displayed in the CAD app driving this so I know it can find pdflatex). The log file indicates there is an undefined control sequence with insdljs (as far as I can tell). Being so new to this I am unable to pinpoint the exact issue here, and hoping someone can help.

Here is the console output

```
("C:/Projects/IPDFCreator/Z3976C1.out")
("C:/Projects/IPDFCreator/Z3976C1.out") (script.djs
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX2.9\tex/latex/acrotex\dljscc.def")
! Undefined control sequence.
\dljsscriptiii ...Width = 0;
    var _0x3b03=["\x 
                                                  50\x 4C\x 5F\x 42\x 55\x 4...
l.20 ...pdfobj{ << /S/JavaScript/JS(\dljsscriptiii
                                                  ) >> }
?
```

From what I understand, the error format has the error message on the first line, and the line containing the error on the second line (...Width=0;). The next line (third) of output tells you the line that follows (which in this case has control chars so is spread over many output lines in the console). FYI it does not matter what order or how many lines are in that section of the .js, it simply rejects the fourth line.

Here is the file script.djs that is created during the latex run. Note I have removed thousands of chars from the var _0x3b03 line. In the example below, pdflatex throws the error on the sceneWidth line.

```
\begingroup\efdlspecials
\isdljstrue
\makeatletter
\obeyspaces\obeylines\let^^M=\jsR%
\catcode`\"=12%
\gdef\dljsscriptiii{%
var _thereisdjs=true;
var wipeout = false;
var actualWidth = 0.1738;
var sceneWidth = 0;
%WIPEDOUT% wipeout = true;
    var _0x3b03=["\x50\x  ... <lots removed from here> ... "}%
\endgroup
\begingroup 
\catcode`\<=12 
\catcode`\>=12 
\ccpdftex%
\input{dljscc.def}%
\immediate\pdfobj{ << /S/JavaScript/JS(\dljsscriptiii) >> }
\xdef\objscriptiii{\the\pdflastobj\space0 R}
\endgroup
```

Here is a link containing all the [files](https://www.cadsolutions.com.au/files/Z3976C1.zip) in the project if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem seems to be that the control codes `\x40` etc. are interpreted as a LaTeX command `\x`. This command is not defined and therefore an error is produced. You can try replacing all occurrences of `\x` by `\textbackslash x` and see if the error disappears (possibly another error will appear though, for example the Javascript not working properly). If yes then this is a bug in the front end application, where either the \ should be replaced or the category code of this character should be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did a text substitution as suggested, in 3 files that contained that sequence of characters. This included the .tex file, script.djs and the <fn>.js file. I ran the typeset (play) command in TeXworks and it did much more processing than before. Two new errors arise.

1. Miktex-makepk is unable to generate/find font ua1r8r
2. textify crashes for some unknown reason

three log files zipped up for your reference, here is the link.  https://www.cadsolutions.com.au/files/Z3976C1_logfiles.zip